# Google App Engine: Firewall blocks https connections with custom domain

Tags: firewall, google-app-engine

I'm trying to restrict the access to the App Engine app which also has the custom domain configured for it.
With no firewall restrictions enabled, I can access it both through the custom and the default .appspot.com domain, both using http and https.
If I add the Allow rule with my external IP and set the default rule to Deny, I end up being unable to access the app using the custom domain and https (getting 403 code), but http with custom domain and http/https with appspot.com domain still work.
Got no clue where to look at, has anyone faced this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your Firewall rules. Also, What is the priority of your Allow rule?

Comment: Priority of Allow rule was set to 1, no other rules except Default.
Screenshot: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqefrizdwnhVg7l0IpxLlgIF5Q9iuA?e=TCurjj

Comment: Could you please tell me if other people are able to reach your appspot?